# Is the cofinality function monotonic?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is the cofinality function $\operatorname{cf}$ monotonic?

I.e., if $\lambda \le \kappa$ for cardinals $\lambda$ and $\kappa$, does it then follow that $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda) \le \operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$?

If this does not hold in general, do there exist conditions on $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ (besides regularity) that allow to make this conclusion in special cases?

Comment: There is something interesting one can add here. There is a conjecture in the theory of determinacy, that the cofinality function is nondecreasing when restricted to successor cardinals below $\Theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, of course not. If you already know that not all cardinals are regular then it suffices to show that. Simply take $\kappa$ to be a singular cardinal and, $\lambda=\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)^+<\kappa$, then $\lambda$ is regular but $\kappa$ has a strictly smaller cofinality despite being larger.

For example, $\aleph_1<\aleph_\omega$ but $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_1)=\aleph_1>\aleph_0=\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)$.

And to your question, no, there are no "easy" cases which are not tantamount to stating "the cofinality function is monotonic in this case".

Comment: How do I know that that I can find a $\kappa$ with $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)^+ < \kappa$? It is not clear to me why simply the existence of singular cardinals imply that the cofinality can take you more than one step back.

Comment: Well, singular cardinals are all limit cardinals. At least assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thanks. I think your answer would benefit from a concrete counter example. As far as I understand, we have $\aleph_1 < \aleph_\omega$, but $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_1) = \aleph_1 > \aleph_0 = \operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)$, i.e. setting $\lambda = \aleph_1$ and $\kappa = \aleph_\omega$ constitutes a counter example. If this is correctly understood, I suggest to add this to the answer to make it more clear for others looking to answer this question.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wanted to let you think it through on your own before putting it in. But now that you've done that, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Excuse my slowness to understand this, but would you elaborate a bit on your somewhat terse second statement "There are no easy cases". Are there really no rules for when $\operatorname{cf}$ can legally be taken on both sides of an inequality? And is there perhaps some nice theorem from which this follows? Some intuition to why this is true?

Comment: For example, consider $cf(\kappa) \le \lambda \le \kappa$. Intiutively (dangerous to follow for infinite cardinals, I know) we must have $cf(cf(\kappa)) = cf(\kappa) \le cf(\lambda)$: Since singular cardinals must be limits, either $\kappa$ is regular (in which case $\lambda = \kappa$), or $\kappa$ is a singular limit cardinal. Can there really exist limit cardinals strictly between $cf(\kappa)$ and $\kappa$?

Is there a good ref. where one can find the rules for calculations that involve $cf$?

(I've not posted a new question, since this is just elaborating my original question. Many thanks.)

Comment: Take $\kappa=\aleph_{\omega_1}$. Then $\lambda$ any $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha\in(1,\omega_1)$. Moreover, if $\lambda$ is singular we even get $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)=\aleph_0$. Which is great. But there are **really** no "good and easy" rules for when the cofinality function preserves inequalities. Again, if $\kappa$ is singular, assuming choice, it is a limit cardinal, and there are ***many*** cardinals between $\kappa$ and its cofinality.

Comment: Thank you. The bug in my head that needed clearing out was the notion that $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)$ and $\kappa$ are at all "close" to each other. Yes, letting $\kappa = \aleph_{\omega_1}$, and $\lambda = \aleph_{\omega}$, obeys $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) < \lambda < \kappa$ ($\aleph_1 < \aleph_{\omega} < \aleph_{\omega_1}$), but $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) = \aleph_1 > \aleph_0 = \operatorname{cf}(\lambda)$).

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, the cofinality of a singular cardinal is almost always "very very very very far" from the singular cardinal. And it is always "infinitely far".